# Write a custom bootloader with the STM32L1 series in C

Tags: c, bootloader, stm32, linker-scripts, flash-memory

I'm writting a Bootloader for an embedded card STM32L152RE in C.
this bootloader is called when a message is sent on the USART. it call an interruption and when the message is received, the bootloader is executed.
Then, i have to flash the memory of my card with the new HEXA code sent on the USART by the computer and reset.

At this point, my bootloader is able to respond to the interruption and read the frames sent by the computer.

I just don't know how to flash my memory. I've got functions in my lib like:
FLASH_Unlock(void), FLASH_ErasePage(uint32_t Page_Address), and FLASH_FastProgramWord(uint32_t Address, uint32_t Data)

I have to erase the flash but not the part where my bootloader is.
That's why i created a new section in my linker descriptor like this

```
  .bootsection :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    KEEP(*(.bootsection)) /* Bootloader code */
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH
```

and my memory is arranged like this :
MEMORY

```
{
  FLASH (rx)      : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 512K
  RAM (xrw)       : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 80K
  MEMORY_B1 (rx)  : ORIGIN = 0x60000000, LENGTH = 0K
}
```

My question is, how do i protect my bootloader from erasing itself when i erase the flash with the new program and how do i flash properly my flash with my HEXA code sent from the USART.

Comment: Since you have control over the segments and where they are loaded, you know where the bootloader is in flash. Put it always at a fixed address in flash, distinct and separate from the rest of the program.

Comment: how do i fix the adress of my bootloader ?

Comment: It's your system, you can decide to use any address you want. For *example* you could reserve X kB at the bottom or the top of the flash memory range, to be used exclusively by the flashing routines. Once you receive a flash-request, you jump to that code which loads the frames and writes them to the other (non-flash-programmer) area.

Comment: yes this is how i imagined the program, the thing is.. i don't know how to set it at the bottom of my flash .. i tried to read the datasheet or examples from the net but i can't find anything

Answer (score 0):

First, you simply must make sure that your bootloader is in the proper place. This ought to be linked to the hardware's requirements, since it needs to know 
where it is in order to run it when the data arrives.

Second, your bootloader code is of course free to inspect the incoming data; it must contain target addresses. So, it can analyze the incoming data and make sure it doesn't collide with where the bootloader resides.

This:

```
FLASH (rx)      : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 512K
```

looks like the entire flash memory, you want to decrease the `LENGTH` to something suitable for the bootloader, probably 16 or 32 KB.

Comment: okay so i need to create a new sector for my boot and decrease the length of my FLASH ?

Comment: @kidz55 The above linker script is just for building the boot code, isn't it? Then you strictly don't need a new segment, but the one you do have needs to say what you want it to say.

Comment: ok . So my bootloader resides at the bottom of my flash but it is declared isnide my flash. My question is , how do i declare, in my linker script, a fix address for my bootloader , what is the command ?

Comment: When you say "put the code for this program in the section `FLASH`", which you do with the `>FLASH` part of the linker script, that is exactly what you're doing. Also, the "bottom" of your flash is of course "inside" it, right? You can't put code where there is no memory.

Comment: yes inside my flash , but how do i specify the bottom of my flash in the linker script ?